# Proper error handling in mongoose query.exec()

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I've digged into Mongoose docs, but I still can't find the information how I should handle errors in `query.exec()`.

```
var query = User.findOne({_id: userId});

    var promise = query.exec(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
            return;
        }
    });
    promise.then(function(user) {
        res.json(user.name);
    });
```

When I pass incorrect userId, I'm getting `Unhandled rejection CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed` error printed to the console.

I thought that `res.json(err)` followed by `return` statement will be enough to handle the error correctly and prevent it from being shown in the console, but it's not. What should I do instead?

Comment: you are using promises why dont you use catch instead of callback in exec
promise.catch(function(err){})

Comment: @AsifSaeed Thanks, this is exactly what I needed to know!

Comment: i was the first one with the answer got nothing :D

Comment: Sorry, I just upvoted the comment, I wish I could accept it as an answer as well :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With callback:

```
var query = User.findOne({_id: userId});
query.exec(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        // handle error
        return;
    }
    // handle success
});
```

With promise:

```
var query = User.findOne({_id: userId});
query.exec().then(function () {
    // handle success
}).catch(function (err) {
    // handle error
});
```

Currently you are mixing both of those styles. Choose one style and stick to it instead.

Comment: can this be 
```const finduser =async () => {
    User.findOne({_id: userId}).exec()
        .then(function () {
    // handle success
    }).catch(function (err) {
    // handle error
});
}```
or is that the .exec() already makes it async @rsp

Comment: It makes sense that OP is mixing both styles. But aren't the mongoose docs mixing them [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population) as well?

Answer (score 1):

With minimal change to your code:

```
var query = User.findOne({_id: userId});

    var promise = query.exec(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
            return Promise.reject(err); // Updated this line
        }
    });
    promise.then(function(user) {
        res.json(user.name);
    });
```

Using promises properly:

```
User.findOne({_.id: userId})
  .then(function(user) {
    return res.json(user.name);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    return res.json(err);
  });
```